# Add security header under api gateway section in serverless: Invalid configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework

I have couple of lambda functions invoked via api gateway and I am using serverless. This is what I have tried,

**serverless.yml**

```
service: my-service
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  profile: xyz
  apiGateway:
    restApiId: # You can specify an existing API Gateway ID if you want to use an existing one
    restApiRootResourceId: # You can specify an existing root resource ID if you want to use an existing one
    response:
      headers:
        Strict-Transport-Security: "'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'"

functions:
  # Define your serverless functions here
  helloWorld:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: 'hello'
          method: get
          cors: true
```

**handler.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports.hello = async (event) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 500,
    error: 'Error'
  };
};
```

But getting

**Warning: Invalid configuration encountered
at 'provider.apiGateway': unrecognized property 'response'**

Any help or suggestion on how to add security in api gateway section instead of adding it for each function

Answer (score 0):

Could you just add the headers to the response in the lambda? Like this:

```
  return {
    statusCode: 500,
    body: 'Error',
    headers: {
      'Strict-Transport-Security': "'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'"
    }
  };
```

Since you're using a proxy and not an integration request, the response from the backend/Lambda is what the user sees. This is how I have added these security headers in the past and you can create a shared library that all your lambda functions can use to reduce the duplication of all these headers.